# Launch Multiple Express Apps Using Nodemon from Same Path

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, nodemon

How can I launch different Express apps from the same root folder?  It is acceptable to use multiple terminal windows.  I would love to use `nodemon` with arguments:

```
nodemon 'landing'
nodemon NODE_APP='app02'
NODE_APP='app02' nodemon
```

I am currently using `node` directly.  This works but does not give me the ability to watch the folders:

```
NODE_APP='app02' node ./server/server.js
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find any combination for `nodemon` that allows this.

As you can see from my folder structure, all server resources are shared:

```
client
    common           <- Express static path 'common'
        assets
        directives
        modules
        vendor
    landing          <- App 01
        modules      <- Modules specific to App 01.
        app.js
        index.html
    signup           <- App 02
        modules      <- Modules specific to App 02.
        app.js
        index.html
    members          <- App 03
        modules      <- Modules specific to App 03.
        app.js
        index.html
server
    config           <- Config sets port & 'public' path to app folder.
    models           <- Common to all apps.
    routes           <- Common to all apps.
    app.js
    server.js
gruntfile.js
nodemon.json
package.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `nodemon` where you are using `node`.  So, instead of this:

```
NODE_APP='app02' node ./server/server.js
```

... use this ...

```
NODE_APP='app02' nodemon ./server/server.js
```